# How to set Eloquent relationship belongsTo THROUGH another model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model Listing that inherits through its belongsTo('Model') relationship should inherently belong to the Manufacturer that its corresponding Model belongs to.

Here's from my Listing model:

```
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id');
    }

    public function manufacturer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Manufacturer', 'models.manufacturer_id');
        /*
        $manufacturer_id = $this->model->manufacturer_id;
        return Manufacturer::find($manufacturer_id)->name;*/
    }
```

and my Manufacturer model:

```
public function listings()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Listing', 'Model', 'manufacturer_id', 'model_id');
}

public function models()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Model', 'manufacturer_id');
}
```

I am able to echo $listing->model->name in a view, but not $listing->manufacturer->name. That throws an error. I tried the commented out 2 lines in the Listing model just to get the effect so then I could echo $listing->manufacturer() and that would work, but that doesn't properly establish their relationship. How do I do this? Thanks.

Revised Listing model (thanks to answerer):

```
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id');
    }

    public function manufacturer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id')
            ->join('manufacturers', 'manufacturers.id', '=', 'models.manufacturer_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution, but it's not extremely straight forward. I've posted it below, but I posted what I think is the better solution first.

You shouldn't be able to access manufacturer directly from the listing, since manufacturer applies to the Model only. Though you can eager-load the manufacturer relationships from the listing object, see below.

```
class Listing extends Eloquent
{
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id');
    }
}

class Model extends Eloquent
{
    public function manufacturer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('manufacturer');
    }
}

class Manufacturer extends Eloquent
{
} 

$listings = Listing::with('model.manufacturer')->all();
foreach($listings as $listing) {
    echo $listing->model->name . ' by ' . $listing->model->manufacturer->name;
}
```

It took a bit of finagling, to get your requested solution working. The solution looks like this:

```
public function manufacturer()
{
    $instance = new Manufacturer();
    $instance->setTable('models');
    $query = $instance->newQuery();

    return (new BelongsTo($query, $this, 'model_id', $instance->getKeyName(), 'manufacturer'))
        ->join('manufacturers', 'manufacturers.id', '=', 'models.manufacturer_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('manufacturers.*'));
}
```

I started off by working with the query and building the response from that. The query I was looking to create was something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturers ma
    JOIN models m on m.manufacturer_id = ma.id
WHERE m.id in (?)
```

The query that would be normally created by doing `return $this->belongsTo('Manufacturer');`

```
select * from `manufacturers` where `manufacturers`.`id` in (?)
```

The `?` would be replaced by the value of `manufacturer_id` columns from the listings table. This column doesn't exist, so a single 0 would be inserted and you'd never return a manufacturer.

In the query I wanted to recreate I was constraining by `models.id`. I could easily access that value in my relationship by defining the foreign key. So the relationship became

```
return $this->belongsTo('Manufacturer', 'model_id');
```

This produces the same query as it did before, but populates the `?` with the model_ids. So this returns results, but generally incorrect results. Then I aimed to change the base table that I was selecting from. This value is derived from the model, so I changed the passed in model to `Model`.

```
return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id');
```

We've now mimic the model relationship, so that's great I hadn't really got anywhere. But at least now, I could make the join to the manufacturers table. So again I updated the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id')
    ->join('manufacturers', 'manufacturers.id', '=', 'models.manufacturer_id');
```

This got us one step closer, generating the following query:

```
select * from `models` 
    inner join `manufacturers` on `manufacturers`.`id` = `models`.`manufacturer_id`
    where `models`.`id` in (?)
```

From here, I wanted to limit the columns I was querying for to just the manufacturer columns, to do this I added the select specification. This brought the relationship to:

return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'model_id')
        ->join('manufacturers', 'manufacturers.id', '=', 'models.manufacturer_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('manufacturers.*'));

And got the query to

```
select manufacturers.* from `models` 
    inner join `manufacturers` on `manufacturers`.`id` = `models`.`manufacturer_id`
    where `models`.`id` in (?)
```

Now we have a 100% valid query, but the objects being returned from the relationship are of type `Model` not `Manufacturer`. And that's where the last bit of trickery came in. I needed to return a `Manufacturer, but wanted it to constrain by the`models`table in the where clause. I created a new instance of Manufacturer and set the table to`models` and manually create the relationship.

It is important to note, that **saving will not work**.

```
$listing = Listing::find(1);
$listing->manufacturer()->associate(Manufacturer::create([]));
$listing->save();
```

This will create a new Manufacturer and then update `listings.model_id` to the new manufacturer's id.

Comment: Thank you so much! A more thorough explanation I could not have asked for. And direct assignment of a manufacturer to a listing isn't supposed to be anyway, so the saving isn't an issue; I have the manufacturer related through the model so that only the model is assigned (in the UI, select a manufacturer, then its models will show, select a model, and the manufacturer will be assigned indirectly via the model saving).

Comment: I'm using the latter solution you provided though, the more compact one... Can you explain what would be the benefit of using your first solution instead?

Answer (score 10):

I guess that this could help, it helped me:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function mechanical()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mechanical::class);
    }
}

class CarPiece extends Model
{
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }

    public function mechanical()
    {
        return $this->car->mechanical();
    }
}
```

At least, it was this need that made me think of the existence of a belongsToThrough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Comment: I've tried something similar but it has some issues. Primarily, `mechanical` on CarPiece can't be eager loaded, because `car` isn't loaded yet. This isn't a huge deal, but is a problem when using jobs, because for some reason jobs insist on eager loaded everything when they deserialize :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (Student Group -> Users -> Poll results):

```php
// poll result

    public function studentGroup(): HasOneDeep
    {
        return $this->hasOneDeepFromRelations($this->user(), (new User())->studentGroup());
    }
```

Comment: Call to undefined method <model class>i::hasOneDeepFromRelations()