# Error seeding table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, seeding

I have a seeder that is the last one called in the DatabaseSeeder. When I call db:seed, I get the following error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                        
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row  
  : a foreign key constraint fails (`catalara`.`models`, CONSTRAINT `models_manufacturer_id_  
  foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`)) (SQL: delete f  
  rom `manufacturers`)                                                                        

  [PDOException]                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row  
  : a foreign key constraint fails (`catalara`.`models`, CONSTRAINT `models_manufacturer_id_  
  foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`))
```

When I specify the class to seed, I just get this:

```
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException]  
  name
```

Any idea as to how to resolve this?

See here for my Listing and Manufacturer model classes:
[How to set Eloquent relationship belongsTo THROUGH another model in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327965/how-to-set-eloquent-relationship-belongsto-through-another-model-in-laravel)

Here is the seeder in question:
    use Faker\Factory as Faker;

```
class ListingsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('listings')->delete();

        $faker = Faker::create();

        $modelCt = count(Model::all());
        $conditions = ['New', 'Used'];
        $layouts = ['Owner', 'Charter'];
        $hull_configs = ['Monohull', 'Catamaran', 'Trimaran'];

        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {

            Listing::create([
                'name' => ucwords($faker->firstName),
                'model_id' => rand(1,$modelCt),
                'length' => rand(1,160),
                'condition' => array_rand(array_flip($conditions)),
                'layout' => array_rand(array_flip($layouts)),
                'hull_config' => array_rand(array_flip($hull_configs)),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

I got it to work for some reason ONLY when running `db:seed --class=ListingsTableSeeder` but not when I run just `db:seed` even though it's the last seeder called in DatabaseSeeder. The same error comes up. But when I run it individually, it works, after I added `protected $guarded = ['id']` to the Listing model for some reason.

But I'd like it to run with the rest of my seeders so why doesn't it and how can it please?

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key is preventing you from seeding the database.

You can either drop it like Maximilian says or within your DatabaseSeeder where you register all your seeders to run put this surrounding all your Seeder classes.

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

//... List of Seeder calls like
$this->call('some class');

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

This will prevent all foreign keys preventing you from seeding your database.

Answer (score 0):

I 'll start form the end

You ll have to add this in your Listing Class model

```
protected $fillable = array('name'); //or/and other fields that you want to exclude from mass assignement exception
```

check [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

For the first error i guess that you have set a foreign key (manufacturer_id) in the models table which references to the manufacture table (id column). So the error probably occurs in the models table seeder when you try to populate the table with a foreign key which does not exist (probably not yet?).

Comment: Well no. When I run the whole db:seed, Eloquent is unguarded; that should void the need for the fillable part. Also, I have this table seeder LAST in the list, when there already exists a Model with id = 2. I am able to seed my Models with their manufacturer_id fk just fine. The Models do exist already though.

Comment: Anyway I'm not even mass-assigning the name, I commented out the loop so now I'm just trying to get it to work with one single record. That's not "mass" anything. It's just one.

Comment: Tried adding that fillable line to the model anyway but yeah it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your FOREIGN key you made earlier. `models_manufacturer_id_foreign`.

So you **can't delete rows** from table.

you need to drop it first.

and remake it when seed is completed.

Comment: I'm not deleting rows from any table. I'm trying to add one sample seed row to my listings table. A Listing has a fk model_id that references the model.id, and the Model has a fk manufacturer_id that references manufacturer.id. I do drop the listings table before seeding it. (see DB::table('listings')->delete();). The other tables exist already so they're ready for referencing.

Comment: you firstly delete rows...
DB::table('listings')->delete();